# C# Errror: Feature 'target-typed object creation' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 9.0 or greater

Tags: c#, syntax-error

How to write this part of code in C# 7.3? The `new()` is throwing an syntax error.

> Feature 'target-typed object creation' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 9.0 or greater

```cs
private static List<ExcelModel> GetSetupData()
{
  List<ExcelModel> output = new()
  {
     new() { Id = 1, Type= "Normal", Mode= "Default" },
     new() { Id = 2, Type= "Normal", Mode= "Test" },
     new() { Id = 3, Type= "Typical", Mode= "Production" }
  };

  return output;
}
```

Comment: `var output = new List<ExcelModel>()` and the same for each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're using C# >=9.0 (where target-typed object creation was introduced), you need to specify the type you're creating when using new

```
 List<ExcelModel> output = new List<ExcelModel>(){
 new ExcelModel() { Id = 1, Type= "Normal", Mode= "Default" }
};
```